# Comparing Treemap to Hashset in Java for spell checking

Tags: java, hashset, spell-checking, treemap

I am going to create a spell checker and I have a txt file of the dictionary that I will be storing inside the hashset, and another file which is going to contain a list of words that will be stores inside a treemap. Then I need to compare the list of words to the dictionary hashmap. How would I iterate through the treemap, and check against the words inside the hashmap to see if the list of words is correct? Lets say I loaded the dictionary inside a hashmap I named `dictionary` and loaded all the list of words from the other file with the key starting from 0 and up and the value being the strings, all stored in a `words` variable which is a treemap. How would I be able to check the individual elements inside `words` against every element inside `dictionary` to see if the words inside `words` is correct?

Comment: Use a set, not a map. Better yet, use a Bloom filter.

Comment: I should just use two hashsets?